# How to reshape a 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a list of numpy arrays which are actually input images to my CNN. However size of each of my image is not cosistent, and my CNN takes only images which are of dimension 224X224. How do I reshape each of my image into the given dimension?
`print(train_images[key].reshape(224, 224,3))`

gives me an output

`ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

I would be very grateful if anybody could help me with this.

Comment: You have choose what kind of shape change is right - scaling, cropping, padding?  Forget `np.reshape` for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New array should have the same amount of values when you are reshaping. What you need is cropping the picture (if it is bigger than 224x224) and padding (if it is smaller than 224x224) or resizing on both occasions.

Cropping is simply slicing with correct indexes:

```
def crop(np_img, size):
    v_start = round((np_img.shape[0] - size[0]) / 2)
    h_start = round((np_img.shape[1] - size[1]) / 2)
    return np_img[v_start:v_start+size[1], h_start:h_start+size[0],:]
```

Padding is slightly more complex, this will create a zeros array in desired shape and plug in the values of image inside:

```
def pad_image(np_img, size):
    v_start = round((size[0] - np_img.shape[0]) / 2)
    h_start = round((size[1] - np_img.shape[1]) / 2)

    result = np.zeros(size)
    result[v_start:v_start+np_img.shape[1], h_start:h_start+np_img.shape[0], :] = np_img

    return result
```

You can also use [np.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) function for it:

```
def pad_image(np_img, size):
    v_dif = size[0] - np_img.shape[0]
    h_dif = size[1] - np_img.shape[1]
    return np.lib.pad(np_img, ((v_dif, 0), (h_dif, 0), (0, 0)), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
```

You may realize padding is a bit different in two functions, I didn't want to over complicate the problem and just padded top and left on the second function. Did the both sides in first one since it was easier to calculate.

And finally for resizing, you better use another library. You can use [scipy.misc.imresize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html), its pretty straightforward. This should do it:

```
imresize(np_img, size)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution @umoto, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways I know to achieve this:

1. Since you're using python, you can use `cv2.resize()`, to resize the image to 224x224. The problem here is going to be distortions.
2. Scale the image to adjust to one of the required sizes (W=224 or H=224) and trim off whatever is extra. There is a loss of information here.
3. If you have the larger image, and a bounding box, use some delta to bounding box to maintain the aspect ratio and then resize down to the required size.

When you reshape a numpy array, the produce of the dimensions **must** match. If not, it'll throw a `ValueError` as you've got. There's no solution using `reshape` to solve your problem, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to resize the image such that the smaller side is equal to 224 and then crop the image to 224x224. Resizing the image to 224x224 may distort the image and can lead to erroneous training. For example, a circle might become an ellipse if the image is not a square. It is important to maintain the original aspect ratio.

Comment: but, won't resizing the smaller size to 224 affect the aspect ratio of the image

Comment: Read carefully - I said ```resize the image such that the smaller side is equal to 224``` not resize only one side.

Comment: Hmm...sorry my bad. But cropping the images leads to loss of information. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: True, cropping the images leads to loss of information but people usually crop from near the middle of the image assuming that the object of interest stays intact. Moreover, you may make multiple crops with a lot of redundant information. This actually helps in improving your training accuracy and is a popular data augmentation method.