# Convert a list of images and labels to np array to train tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the tutorial about convolutional neural networks. In this function, I use:

```
# Train the model
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": X_train},
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=100,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
 mnist_classifier.train(
    input_fn=train_input_fn,
    steps=20000,
    hooks=[logging_hook])
```

where

```
type(X_train)
```

list

```
type(y_train)
```

list

```
y_train[0]
```

'0'

```
X_train[0].shape
```

(30, 29, 3)

```
type(X_train[0])
```

numpy.ndarray

```
len(X_train)
```

39209

```
len(y_train)
```

39209

I get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X_train` looks like a **list of** numpy arrays and tensorflow expects a numpy array, you can simply convert it to a numpy array by:

```
X_train = np.array(X_train)
```

or using [numpy.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy-asarray) function, which does the exact same thing as above:

```
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
```

Bear in mind, all your images should have the same dimensions for conversion to work.

Comment: Thank you. How can I convert my images to the same size without using opencv. I would like to have 32 x 32 x 3 images.

Comment: @Maggie, OpenCV would make things easier, but alternatively you can also use scipy's image related libraries especially [imresize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html). But if you only want to use numpy, you can easily [crop or pad images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44451615/826970) with vanilla numpy functions, while resizing would be a lot more complex.